# How can I get two graphs side by side instead of one on top of the other?

Tags: tkz-graph

How could I get these two graphs side by side?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}  
  [->,scale=0.6,auto=center,every node/.style={circle,fill=blue!20}] 

  \node [label=left:t] (a1) at (1,7) {$\infty$};  
  \node [label=above:v] (a2) at (4,6.5)  {$\infty$}; 
  \node [label=right:u] (a3) at (7.5,7)  {$\infty$};  
  \node [label=left:w] (a4) at (1,4.6) {$\infty$};  
  \node [label=below right :x](a5) at (5,4.2)  {0};  
  \node [label=below:z] (a6) at (4.2,1.5)  {$\infty$};  
  \node [label=right:y] (a7) at (7.8,4.6)  {$\infty$};  

  \draw (a1) -- (a2)  ;
  \draw (a2) -- (a3);
\draw (a2) -- (a4);
\draw (a2) -- (a6);
\draw (a3) -- (a7);
\draw (a7) -- (a5);
\draw (a5) -- (a4);
\draw (a4) -- (a6);
\draw (a4) -- (a1);
\draw (a6) -- (a5);
\draw (a6) -- (a7);
\draw (a5) -- (a3);
\draw (a5) -- (a2);

\end{tikzpicture} 


\begin{tikzpicture}  
  [->,scale=0.6,auto=center,every node/.style={circle,fill=blue!20}] 

  \node (a1) at (1,7) {t};  
  \node (a2) at (4,6.5)  {v}; 
  \node (a3) at (7.5,7)  {u};  
  \node (a4) at (1,4.6) {w};  
  \node (a5) at (5,4.2)  {x};  
  \node (a6) at (4.2,1.5)  {z};  
  \node (a7) at (7.8,4.6)  {y};  

  \draw (a1) -- (a2);
  \draw (a2) -- (a3);
\draw (a2) -- (a4);
\draw (a2) -- (a6);
\draw (a3) -- (a7);
\draw (a7) -- (a5);
\draw (a5) -- (a4);
\draw (a4) -- (a6);
\draw (a4) -- (a1);
\draw (a6) -- (a5);
\draw (a6) -- (a7);
\draw (a5) -- (a3);
\draw (a5) -- (a2);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Put them into a table, or in two minipages.

Comment: tikzpictures are positioned by the same code that positions letters, they are side by side by default. But you have then in separate paragraphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way would be to use minipages:

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % your stuff
    \end{tikzpicture}  
\end{minipage}%        <- This '%' is important
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % your stuff
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
```

It is also possible to use subfigure from subcaption package:

```
\begin{figure}[hbt]
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
        % your stuff
        \caption{name of first subfigure}
    \end{subfigure}%    <- This '%' is important to prevent line break... I think you can also use ~
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
        % your stuff
        \caption{name of second subfigure}
    \end{subfigure}
\caption{name of figure}
\end{figure}
```

I hope this helps ;-)

Comment: they would by side by side by default, you don't need minipage

Comment: note your comment about needing `%` also applies to minipages but you don't have a % in your first example. You can not get two .5\textwidth minipages on a line if you put a word space between them. (`~` would make an over full box)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks for pointing this out. I correct this one

Answer (score 3):

Or even simplier, use a scope with xshift.
[image: two pictures side by side]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}  
      [->,scale=0.6,auto=center,every node/.style={circle,fill=blue!20}] 
    
      \node [label=left:t] (a1) at (1,7) {$\infty$};  
      \node [label=above:v] (a2) at (4,6.5)  {$\infty$}; 
      \node [label=right:u] (a3) at (7.5,7)  {$\infty$};  
      \node [label=left:w] (a4) at (1,4.6) {$\infty$};  
      \node [label=below right :x](a5) at (5,4.2)  {0};  
      \node [label=below:z] (a6) at (4.2,1.5)  {$\infty$};  
      \node [label=right:y] (a7) at (7.8,4.6)  {$\infty$};  
    
      \draw (a1) -- (a2)  ;
      \draw (a2) -- (a3);
    \draw (a2) -- (a4);
    \draw (a2) -- (a6);
    \draw (a3) -- (a7);
    \draw (a7) -- (a5);
    \draw (a5) -- (a4);
    \draw (a4) -- (a6);
    \draw (a4) -- (a1);
    \draw (a6) -- (a5);
    \draw (a6) -- (a7);
    \draw (a5) -- (a3);
    \draw (a5) -- (a2);

    \begin{scope}[xshift=10cm] 
    
      \node (a1) at (1,7) {t};  
      \node (a2) at (4,6.5)  {v}; 
      \node (a3) at (7.5,7)  {u};  
      \node (a4) at (1,4.6) {w};  
      \node (a5) at (5,4.2)  {x};  
      \node (a6) at (4.2,1.5)  {z};  
      \node (a7) at (7.8,4.6)  {y};  
    
      \draw (a1) -- (a2);
      \draw (a2) -- (a3);
    \draw (a2) -- (a4);
    \draw (a2) -- (a6);
    \draw (a3) -- (a7);
    \draw (a7) -- (a5);
    \draw (a5) -- (a4);
    \draw (a4) -- (a6);
    \draw (a4) -- (a1);
    \draw (a6) -- (a5);
    \draw (a6) -- (a7);
    \draw (a5) -- (a3);
    \draw (a5) -- (a2);
    \end{scope} 
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

`tikzpicture` are positioned by the same code that positions letters, so your question is the same as asking how to make two X come side by side.

You have

```
X

X
```

So they come one above the other.

You could have

```
XX
```

for side by side, or

```
X
X
```

for side by side with a word space.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}  
  [->,scale=0.6,auto=center,every node/.style={circle,fill=blue!20}] 

  \node [label=left:t] (a1) at (1,7) {$\infty$};  
  \node [label=above:v] (a2) at (4,6.5)  {$\infty$}; 
  \node [label=right:u] (a3) at (7.5,7)  {$\infty$};  
  \node [label=left:w] (a4) at (1,4.6) {$\infty$};  
  \node [label=below right :x](a5) at (5,4.2)  {0};  
  \node [label=below:z] (a6) at (4.2,1.5)  {$\infty$};  
  \node [label=right:y] (a7) at (7.8,4.6)  {$\infty$};  

  \draw (a1) -- (a2)  ;
  \draw (a2) -- (a3);
\draw (a2) -- (a4);
\draw (a2) -- (a6);
\draw (a3) -- (a7);
\draw (a7) -- (a5);
\draw (a5) -- (a4);
\draw (a4) -- (a6);
\draw (a4) -- (a1);
\draw (a6) -- (a5);
\draw (a6) -- (a7);
\draw (a5) -- (a3);
\draw (a5) -- (a2);

\end{tikzpicture} 
\begin{tikzpicture}  
  [->,scale=0.6,auto=center,every node/.style={circle,fill=blue!20}] 

  \node (a1) at (1,7) {t};  
  \node (a2) at (4,6.5)  {v}; 
  \node (a3) at (7.5,7)  {u};  
  \node (a4) at (1,4.6) {w};  
  \node (a5) at (5,4.2)  {x};  
  \node (a6) at (4.2,1.5)  {z};  
  \node (a7) at (7.8,4.6)  {y};  

  \draw (a1) -- (a2);
  \draw (a2) -- (a3);
\draw (a2) -- (a4);
\draw (a2) -- (a6);
\draw (a3) -- (a7);
\draw (a7) -- (a5);
\draw (a5) -- (a4);
\draw (a4) -- (a6);
\draw (a4) -- (a1);
\draw (a6) -- (a5);
\draw (a6) -- (a7);
\draw (a5) -- (a3);
\draw (a5) -- (a2);

\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Obviously, you're totally right. I just assumed that OP wanted them aligned in a *better* way than just side by side (with the vertical gap). Hence the `scope`. But thank you Sir, for pointing that particular property of `tikzpicture`.

Comment: @SebGlav yes your answer is the correct tikz answer that the OP should accept, I wanted to stress the point (that comes up for  images and other things as well as tikz) that they have no actual positioning logic themseleves. Also act as a counter to the other answer which has some issues.